# jinja2 UndefinedError: 'resultado' is undefined | FLASK

Tags: python, html, forms, flask, jinja2

I'm working with Flask. I have one route and I want to redirect it to other route when pressing a button, but I want to pass an argument. This is my route:

```
@app.route('/actualize_product.html', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def actualize_product():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("post")
        query1 = """
            SELECT id FROM BD.producto
            WHERE id=""" + str(request.form['product_id'])
        conection = connect()
        resultt = conection.execute(query1)[0]
        print(resultt)
        return redirect(url_for('/edit_product.html', resultado = resultt)) #Line where I'm redirecting


    query = "SELECT * FROM BD.Producto ALLOW FILTERING; "
    conection = connect()
    result = conection.execute(query)
    return render_template('actualize_product.html', products = result)
```

And this is the route I want it to be redirected

```
@app.route('/edit_product.html', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit_product():
    print("edit")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        print("Im already here")

    return render_template('edit_product.html')
```

The problem is that the edit_product.html is a file where I use jinja2

```
      <h2>Id del producto: {{resultado.id}} </h2> <br>
      <form action="app.py" method="get" onsubmit="return formEsValido()">
        <input type= "hidden" value = "{{resultado.id}}" id = "id" name = "id">
        <label for="product_name"> Nuevo nombre del Producto: </label>
        <input type="text" name="product_name" id="product_name" class="form-control">
        <label for="product_price"> Nuevo precio del Producto: </label>
        <input type="text" name="product_price" id="product_price" class="form-control">
        <label for="descripction"> Nueva descripcion del Producto: </label>
        <input type="text" name="description" id="description" class="form-control">
        <label for="stock">Nuevo stock del Producto</label>
        <input type="text" name="stock" id="stock" class="form-control">
        <br>  
        <button class="btn btn-primary"id="index-buttons" type="submit">Editar Producto</button>              
      </form>
  </div>
```

If I use render_template instead of redirect, it won't work because after clicking on that button, the route will be /actualize_product.html and I want it to change to /edit_product.html' because I have a form there, I don't know how to pass that variable called "resultado" to jinja2 using redirect.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is the id, you can pass it as an url parameter.

```
@app.route('/actualize')
def actualize():
    return redirect(url_for('edit', id=123))

@app.route('/edit')
def edit():
    id = request.args.get('id')
    return render_template('edit.html', id=id)
```